# Is there a way to peek the value in GSON or rewind nextString?

Tags: java, gson

I'm using GSON, Java, Kotlin and Android.

Due to factors outside my control, backend is sending us JSON date values in several formats that GSON can't handle by default. I thought I'd make a custom `TypeAdapter` to handle it.

I still need to handle many standard formatted Dates as well.

I currently have this:

```
private class DateTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = (TypeAdapter<T>)gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        if (!Date.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) return null;
        //TODO: maybe avoid creating a new object on each method call?
        return (TypeAdapter<T>)new TypeAdapter<Date>() {
            public Date read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    reader.nextNull();
                    return null;
                }
                String dateString = reader.nextString();

                try {
                    if (yearMonthDayPattern.matcher(dateString).matches()) {
                        return yearMonthDayFormat.parse(dateString);
                    } else if (dateHourMinutePattern.matcher(dateString).matches()) {
                        return dateHourMinuteFormat.parse(dateString);
                    } else {TypeToken<Date>() {});
                        return (Date)delegate.read(reader);
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Timber.wtf(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, Date value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, (T)value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here's the problem I'm running into: I must consume the value (using `nextString()` in order to check and see if it is one of the weird formats, and if so, which one. But when I pass regular Date values to the `delegate` for default handling, the `delegate` assumes the value has not been called yet and tries to advance the stream, resulting in an error. How can I work around this?

If there was a way to observe the value without consuming it, I could call that, check that value in the first two if statements, and then call `nextString()` if either of them passes to manually advance the stream. But `peek()` seems to only return a type, not a value.

If there was a way to "rewind" the stream, I could call `nextString()` exactly as I am doing now, then rewind it by one before passing the call to the delegate. But I don't see such a method in the `JsonReader` API.

Or perhaps there is a different way to access the default Date parsing behavior? Or perhaps some completely different idea I have not considered.

Comment: If I were you, I would try to [generate](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) GSON POJOs using yous JSON as input, maybe it will be able to generate the proper wrappers and you don't have to cope with TypeAdapters. If it is not able to do that, then it would be good to see at least the problemmatic part of your JSON (please update your question with it if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to read the next value without consuming it, or to rewind the stream to un-consume it. I also can't find a different way to work with the delegate to access the default behavior. I did find the class that does the default date parsing:
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java

Unfortunately, although its constructors allow for passing in ONE extra Date format, you can't pass in two, which is what I need. The class is `final` and the method I need is `private`. I even tried copying and pasting the class into my code so I could modify it to get the functionality I need, which would have been less than ideal--but the GSON library is set up so some of the classes DefaultDateTypeAdapter requires cannot be accessed from other apps, and I didn't want to copy and paste multiple files into my app...

Fortunately, I then noticed that the `deserializeToDate()` method will actually take the original date String and set it as the message of the `Exception` it throws when it cannot parse a value. That means that I can call the default parser, and if it fails, pull that date string out and parse it however I want.

This is what I ended up with, and it seems to work fine:

```
private class DateTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    private DateFormat yearMonthDayFormat = DateFormatters.getDateFormatInUserTimeZone(FORMAT_TYPE_YYYY_MM_DD);
    private DateFormat dateHourMinuteFormat = DateFormatters.getDateFormatInUserTimeZone(DateFormatters.FORMAT_TYPE_ISO8601_NO_SECONDS);

    private Pattern yearMonthDayPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$");
    private Pattern dateHourMinutePattern = Pattern.compile(
            "[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        if (!Date.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) return null;

        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new TypeAdapter<Date>() {
            public Date read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    reader.nextNull();
                    return null;
                }

                try {
                    return (Date) delegate.read(reader);
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
                    // DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate sets the date string as the JsonSyntaxException message,
                    // allowing us to try parsing it our own way.
                    String dateString = jse.getMessage();

                    try {
                        // If default date parsing fails, try one of the two funky new formats. Here we're using
                        // precompiled regexes for performance, but we could also try parsing and checking for
                        // ParseExceptions - that's what DefaultDateTypeAdapter does.
                        if (yearMonthDayPattern.matcher(dateString).matches()) {
                            return yearMonthDayFormat.parse(dateString);
                        } else if (dateHourMinutePattern.matcher(dateString).matches()) {
                            return dateHourMinuteFormat.parse(dateString);
                        } else {
                            throw jse;
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException pe) {
                        Timber.wtf(pe);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, Date value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, (T)value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any explicit reference to DefaultDateTypeAdapter since delegates are still fine. Also, the whole and the single point of streamed reading is reading it *once* without rewinding (why do you need to pay for buffering if you don't need it? what is the depth of rewinding? what if buffered JSON tokens are too large to keep in memory especially for huge objects and strings?). Once you've consumed a value, you can choose what to do with it: discard it away, print it out, keep it, store it, whatever it. Totally up to you. Now, since you have it consumed, what if you convert the value to a JSON tree representation? In general, it's a well-formed JSON value that does not need to be re-read, and rewinding is merely unapplicable here: this is just a representation in memory you can traverse in arbitrary order up to your needs. Having that said, take a look at [fromJsonTree](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html#fromJsonTree-com.google.gson.JsonElement-). It can consume trees converting them to streams that can be consumed by underlying type adapters (and they don't even know they are consuming not streams, but trees). So, the only thing you have to change

```
return (Date)delegate.read(reader);
```

to

```
retutn (Date)delegate.fromJsonTree(new JsonPrimitive(dateString));
```

That should work.

(lsh)

Answer (score 0):

How about just simply creating and registering `JsonDeserializer<Date>` ? Something like:

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    // for default date parsing
    private final Gson innerGgson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, 
                            JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)
            throws JsonParseException {

        try {
            return innerGgson.fromJson(jsonElement, Date.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // default parsing failed, try other formats
        }

        return parseDate(jsonElement.getAsString());
    }

    // all the possible date formats listed here 
    private static final DateFormat[] DATE_FORMATS = new DateFormat[] {
            new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"),
            new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy") };

    // as an example, in this method, first try to instantiate all the 'normal' 
    // dateformats then something like it has now:
    // trying all the date formats, except ticks that then can be tried also
    // separately
    private Date parseDate(String dateString) {
        for (DateFormat df : DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                return df.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // just try the next
            }
        }
        // finally, if not parsed return null or throw something
        return null;
    }

}
```

registering:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
    .create();
```

I think you still realize there just is no solution if the formats you obtain can be  interpreted to more than one `Date`s, meaning that if you get `01/02/2018` is it **Jan 2nd 2018** or **Feb 1st 2018** unless you have some base assumptions?

Comment: The problem is that this does not handle default date parsing, only date parsing in the two new formats. As I explained in my question and answer, one of the trickiest bits was handling both the strange new formats, and the normal date formats that most of the app uses.

Comment: That is not a problem,really, this just was not complete code. See my update in a minute.